# Generating a string series using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to generate a series of string that follows a common pattern - `string_1, string_2, string_3, ... , string_300` and store it in a list for later user.

This is what I attempted to do:

```
import re
import rstr
my_list = []
for i in range(300):
    my_list.append(rstr.xeger('tfidfq1_' + r'\d+'))
print(my_list)
```

It returns me the following output (random integer values attached to the pattern) :

```
['tfidfq1_136661297340782794491184216459404707300', 'tfidfq1_2589909625', 'tfidfq1_18727788172555473792414335', 'tfidfq1_74398064004349014500', 'tfidfq1_717988289733122715', 'tfidfq1_837110644512955951526642498807464108955072901448324651', 'tfidfq1_1242901657149645729287068201772019', 'tfidfq1_65744803203582034865965176556801518051952025765063847353492809122226185458184605945', 'tfidfq1_7573483728912690942438243920733684460197341320213759562902745',...]
```

Expected output:

```
['tfidfq1_1','tfidfq1_2','tfidfq1_3',...,'tfidfq1_300']
```

What is the correct way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want random strings why are you using `rstr`?

Comment: If you have Python 3.6, you could do `[f'tfidfq1_{u}' for u in range(1, 301)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for `regex` neither `rstr`, you can do something like this, using your already written `for` loop:

```
for i in range(300):
    my_list.append('tfidfq1_' + str(i+1))
```